# HTML JQuery .on('change') нужна помощь

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть код:

```
            $('select').on('change', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('length')) {
                    let unit = $(this).val(),
                    foru = $(this).attr('data-for'),
                    oval = $(foru).val();

                    if (unit == 1) {

                        $(foru).attr('data-value', oval)

                    } else if (unit == 2) {

                        nval = parseFloat(oval) / 100;
                        $(foru).attr('data-value', nval)

                    } else if (unit == 3) {

                        nval = parseFloat(oval) / 39.37;
                        $(foru).attr('data-value', nval)

                    }
                }
            });
```

Вроде все отлично работает с элементами select, но только с теми, которые изначально были на странице. При добавлении новых элементов select, эта функция их не затрагивает. Как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод с "делегированием", например

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {...
    ...
}
```

Вместо `document` может быть любой элемент, который содержит в себе `select`, но при этом всегда на странице, и динамически не подгружается как-то еще.

О делегировании можно почитать тут: https://webref.ru/dev/jqfundamentals/events

и здесь: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On#.D0.9F.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.28.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_selector.29

Answer (score 0):

Нужно понимать как работает браузер с веб страницей, как он её строит, и как он воспроизводит JS.

Дело в том, что браузер строит DOM, и если встречает JS, то выполняет его, как раз это и происходит в вашем случае. Браузер сформировал элементы `<select></select>` и теперь JS к ним обращается `$('select')` и добавляет им слушателя. ВНИМАНИЕ это происходит при загрузке страницы. Манипуляции с DOM такие как добавление новых `<select></select>` скрипт `$('select').on('change'.....` не перезапускается, а значит и слушателя у нового элемента не будет.

Однако решение задачи довольно простое.

Заверните весь ваш код `$('select').on('change'.....` в функцию. Первый раз вызовите её когда страница будет загружена. А последующие разы тогда, когда будут добавляться новые элементы на экран.

ps. чисто совет, сначала почитайте про JS затем переходите к Jquery иначе вопросов будет очень много от того, что нет понимания как работает JS

Comment: Можно также сделать через `$(document).on("change","select",function(){})`, тогда браузер будет отслеживать и динамически добавляемые элементы.

Comment: @fixer кстати да, хорошая идея

Comment: Перезапускать `$('select').on('change'...` каждый раз - плохая идея, потому что событие будет многократно добавляться и на те элементы, которые уже получали его. Может оказаться, что при "change", функция начнет выполняться раз 100)